# Why an assertion failed during the linking phase?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, ld

I want to statically link [`libdds.a`](http://privat.bahnhof.se/wb758135/bridge/dll.html) to a simple C++ application (to make some tests). Here is my C++ code (the file is named `bridge.cpp`):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't use functions in `libdds.a` for the moment but I want to make sure compilation works well before. So I try to compile:

```
$ g++ -Wall -o bridge bridge.cpp -L. -ldds
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 6 [Abandon], core dumped
compilation terminated.
ld: ../../src/lto-plugin/lto-plugin.c :388 : dump_symtab:  assertion « resolution != LDPR_UNKNOWN » failed.
```

Here are the versions of `g++` and `ld`:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
```

I'm not using any IDE and I compile from command line with the exact previous command. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

What this error means and how can I correct it?

Comment: There's a lot of specific information missing to reproduce your particular problem, add all that please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What information do you need?

Comment: All about your OS and development environment.

Comment: This type of problem is often specific to a versions of g++ (or the linker it uses), the IDE or build environment, the operating system it all runs on,  what libdds.a is,  how that library was built, and a whole bunch of things.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I add the information. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: @Peter Where can I find information about `libdds.a`? The website who provided it doesn't give many information. Should I compile it myself? Or maybe does it exist some tools to get those information?

Comment: @Pierre _"Should I compile it myself?"_ That's probably the best option to make it compatiple with your development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that at least one symbol can't be resolved by `lto-plugin`. Indeed, the static library `dds.a` was compiled with an older version of GCC. For instance, if you try to read one object file in it with `lto1`, you'll get this error:

```
$ /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto1 Par.o
Reading object files: Par.olto1: fatal error: bytecode stream generated with LTO version 2.1 instead of the expected 4.1
```

To correct it, you have two choices: diable LTO or recompile `dds.a` (as suggested in the comments).

To disable LTO, you can use the `-fno-use-linker-plugin` GCC option but you will get another error:

```
$ g++ -Wall -fno-use-linker-plugin -o bridge bridge.cpp -L. -ldds
/usr/bin/ld : skipping incompatible ./libdds.a when searching for -ldds
```

Indeed, the objects file are in `elf32-i386` format and you try to link them with `elf64-x86-64` file format:

```
$ objdump -p Par.o
Par.o:     file format elf32-i386
$ g++ -c bridge.cpp 
$ objdump -p bridge.o 
bridge.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
```

At this point, the only good solution to link `dds.a` to your program is to recompile it with the same compiler you will use to compile your final application.